# Missing Angular modules in Ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, angularfire, ionic3

There is code that I've tested on a different computer and found to work for Ionic, but right now when running it on my personal PC I'm facing these errors:

```
[16:08:05]  typescript: home/ghylama/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, line: 3 
            Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 

       L2:  import { FirebaseAppConfig } from './interfaces';
       L3:  import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
       L4:  declare const FirebaseAppName: InjectionToken<string>;

[16:08:05]  typescript: home/ghylama/node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module '@angular/core'. 

       L1:  import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  import { FirebaseAppConfig } from '../interfaces';
```

I'm using Ubuntu MATE. 
Ionic version : 3.4.0

npm version: 4.6.0

I tried changing the ownership of the folder in node_modules to myself. Didn't help.

I ran

```
sudo npm install g angularfire firebase
```

already.

The Html file:

```html
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
    <button (click)="login(email,password)" ion-button color="dark" outline>Log In</button>
   <button (click)="logout()" ion-button color="dark" outline>Log Out</button>
      <button (click)="signin()" ion-button color="dark" clear>Or create an account</button>

    <p style="color:red;">{{errorMessage}}</p>

    <!--<div> {{ (af.auth | async)?.uid }} </div>-->
  </ion-list>


</ion-content>
```

The .ts file:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Mainmenu } from '../mainmenu/mainmenu';
import { SignIn } from '../sign-in/sign-in';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  errorMessage:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public af: AngularFire) {

    af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
      if(auth) {
        console.log('logged in');
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
      }
    });


    this.errorMessage = "";
  }
  login(Email,Password) {
    //Email = "hamada@hamada.com";
    //Password = "abc123";
    this.af.auth.login({ email: Email, password: Password })
      .then((info)=>{
          this.navCtrl.push(Mainmenu);
        },
        (erro)=>{
          console.log("Error " + erro);
          this.errorMessage = "Email/Password are incorrect";
        }
      );
  }
  logout() {

    this.af.auth.logout();
  }

  signin()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(SignIn);
  }

}
```

Comment: npm v5 has a bunch of issues.. try using a lower version

Comment: I've just downgraded to 4.6.0, problem persists :(

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `angularfire2` after installing `angularfire` **Version 1**.

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

Check [the installation instruction](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#install).

Make sure to remove angularfire.

```
npm uninstall angularfire --save
```

Also you dont need use `g`. That is for global installation and it wont find angular modules as it will be installed locally in your project.

Comment: The errors decreased, but this one is still there:

Module '"/home/ghylama/again/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AngularFire'.

Comment: maybe this will help https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this steps placed in your project directory (cd path-to-project-folder):

1. npm install --save angularfire

2. npm install --save firebase

This should be enough, but if the error persist, then keep in your project directory and run:

1. rm -rf node_modules

2. npm install

Comment: npm WARN angularfire@2.3.0 requires a peer of angular@^1.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angularfire@2.3.0 requires a peer of firebase@3.x.x but none was installed.
ghylama@ghylama-CF-19KDRAXCM:~/kmn$ 

Should I be worried about these warnings?

Comment: Please update your dependencies: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516